# Проблема со счетчиком во фрагменте CartFragment

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, activity

При изменений количества товара увеличивается и его цена, но когда в корзине нажимаешь на товар чтобы посмотреть на товар подробнее а потом выходишь обратно и меняешь количество товара то не меняется цена, искал долго лазил по разным форумам не нашел решения и сам не смог додуматся, помогите чем сможете

CartFragment

```
class CartFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentCartBinding? = null
    private val launcher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
        if (it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            requestProducts()
        }
    }

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding
    lateinit var cartViewModel: CartViewModel
    var adapter: CartRecyclerAdapter? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        cartViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this)[CartViewModel::class.java]

        (activity as? AppCompatActivityWithLoading)?.setViewModel(cartViewModel)

        _binding = FragmentCartBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding!!.root


        binding?.bottomBar?.isVisible = false
        if (context?.let { User.isLogged(it) } == false){
            binding?.loginButton?.isVisible = true
            binding?.noDataView?.isVisible = true
        } else {
            binding?.loginButton?.isVisible = false
            binding?.noDataView?.isVisible = false
            requestProducts()
        }

        adapter = context?.let { CartRecyclerAdapter(it) }
        adapter?.onProductClickListener = {
            val product = MenuProduct(
                it.product,
                it.name,
                null,
                variant = MenuProduct.ProductVariant(it.v_id, it.price, null, null),
                image = it.image?.thumbnail,
                rating = MenuProduct.Rating(0f,0)
            )
            val bundle = bundleOf(DetailedProductFragment.MENU_PRODUCT to product)
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_detailedProduct, bundle)
        }
        adapter?.onRemoveListener = {
            deleteProduct(it)
        }
        adapter?.onWarnMaxCount = {
            AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setMessage(getString(R.string.sorry_out_of_stock))
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok)) { dialog, _ ->
                    dialog.dismiss()
                }.create().show()
        }
        adapter?.onUpdateListener = {it, callback ->
            cartViewModel.updateAmount(it){
                if (it){
                    configureBottomBar()
                }
                callback(it)
            }
        }
        binding?.cartRecycler?.adapter = adapter
        cartViewModel.cartData.observe(this){
            adapter?.differ?.submitList(it)
            configureBottomBar()
            (activity as? MainActivity)?.setBadge(cartViewModel.getCartCount)
        }

        val resultThank  = findNavController().currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.getLiveData<Boolean>(
            ThankYouFragment.SUCCESS
        )?.value
        if (resultThank == true){
            findNavController().currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set(ThankYouFragment.SUCCESS, null)
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_myOrders)
        }
        val result  = findNavController().currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.getLiveData<Boolean>(
            CheckoutFragment.ORDER_SUCCESS
        )?.value
        if (result == true){
            findNavController().currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set(CheckoutFragment.ORDER_SUCCESS, null)
            cartViewModel.cleanCart()
            requestProducts()
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_thankyou)
        }
        binding?.checkoutButton?.setOnClickListener {
            val arr = arrayListOf<Map<String, Number>>()
            cartViewModel.cartData.value?.forEach {
                arr.addAll(it.products.map { hashMapOf("variant" to it.v_id, "count" to it.quantity, "price" to (it.price*it.quantity.toDouble())) })
            }
            val bundle = bundleOf(CART_PRODUCTS to arr)
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_checkout, bundle)
        }

        binding?.buttonRetry?.setOnClickListener {
            requestProducts()
        }
        binding?.loginButton?.setOnClickListener {
            launcher.launch(Intent(context, LoginActivity::class.java))
        }

        return root
    }

    private fun requestProducts(){
        productLoading(true)
        cartViewModel.getCartProducts {
            productLoading(false, it)
            adapter?.differ?.submitList(it)
        }
    }

    private fun productLoading(isLoading: Boolean, data: List<Any>? = null){
        binding?.cartRecycler?.isVisible = !isLoading && data?.isNotEmpty() == true
        binding?.errorMessage?.isVisible = !isLoading && data == null
        binding?.noDataView?.isVisible = !isLoading && data?.isEmpty() == true
        binding?.loginButton?.isVisible = false
        binding?.shimmerViewContainer?.isVisible = isLoading
    }

    private fun configureBottomBar() {
        val total = cartViewModel.cartTotal
        binding?.bottomBar?.isVisible = total != null
        binding?.mainPrice?.text = PriceFormatter.getPrice(total)
        (activity as? MainActivity)?.setBadge(cartViewModel.getCartCount)
    }

    private fun deleteProduct(pId: Int) {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.are_you_sure_delete))
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.yes)) { _, _ ->
                // Delete selected note from database
                cartViewModel.removeProduct(pId)
            }
            .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.no)) { dialog, _ ->
                // Dismiss the dialog
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
        val alert = builder.create()
        alert.show()
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

//    override fun onResume() {
//        super.onResume()
//        requestProducts()
//    }

    companion object {
        const val CART_PRODUCTS = "cartProducts"
    }
}
```

CartRepository

```
class CartRepository {

    suspend fun getCartCount(): Int {
        val request = Network.apiClient.getCartCount()

        if (request.failed){
            Log.e("mylog", request.exception?.stackTraceToString() ?: "Errrror")
            return 0
        }

        if (!request.isSuccessful){
            return 0
        }

        return request.body.data ?: 0
    }

    suspend fun getCartProducts(): List<CartItem>? {
        val request = Network.apiClient.getCartProducts()

        if (request.failed){
            Log.e("mylog", request.exception?.stackTraceToString() ?: "Errrror")
            return null
        }

        if (!request.isSuccessful){
            return null
        }

        return request.body.data
    }

    suspend fun removeFromCart(variantId: Int): Boolean {
        val request = Network.apiClient.removeFromCart(variantId)

        if (request.failed){
            Log.e("mylog", request.exception?.stackTraceToString() ?: "Errrror")
            return false
        }

        if (!request.isSuccessful){
            return false
        }

        return request.body.isSuccess
    }

    suspend fun updateAmount(variantId: Int, amount: Number): Boolean {
        val request = Network.apiClient.updateCartProduct(variantId, amount)

        if (request.failed){
            Log.e("mylog", request.exception?.stackTraceToString() ?: "Errrror")
            return false
        }

        if (!request.isSuccessful){
            return false
        }

        return request.body.isSuccess
    }
}
```

CartViewModel

```
class CartViewModel : ViewModelWithLoading() {

    val getCartCount: Int get() {
        var count = 0
        _cartData.value?.forEach { it.products.forEach {
            count += if (it.isFloat) 1 else it.quantity.toInt()
        } }
        return count
    }
    private val cartRepository = CartRepository()

    private val _cartData = MutableLiveData<List<CartItem>?>()
    val cartData: LiveData<List<CartItem>?> = _cartData

    val cartTotal: Double?
        get(){
            if (_cartData.value == null)
                return null
            var total = 0.0
            _cartData.value?.forEach {
                it.products.forEach {
                    total += it.price * it.quantity.toDouble()
                }
            }
            return if (total == 0.0) null else total
        }

    fun getCartProducts(callback: (List<CartItem>?) -> Unit) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val response = cartRepository.getCartProducts()
            _cartData.postValue(response)
            callback(response)
        }
    }

    fun removeProduct(variantId: Int) {
        startLoading()
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val response = cartRepository.removeFromCart(variantId)
            if (response) {
                val list = cartRepository.getCartProducts()
                _cartData.postValue(list)
            }
            stopLoading()
        }
    }
    fun updateAmount(cartProduct: CartItem.CartProduct, callback: (Boolean)->Unit) {
        startLoading()
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val response = cartRepository.updateAmount(cartProduct.v_id, cartProduct.quantity)
            callback(response)
            stopLoading()
        }
    }

    fun cleanCart() {
        _cartData.postValue(null)
    }
}
```

CartRecyclerAdapter

```
class CartRecyclerAdapter(val context: Context): RecyclerView.Adapter<CartRecyclerAdapter.CartItemViewHolder>(){

    var onRemoveListener: ((Int)->Unit)? = null
    var onUpdateListener: ((CartItem.CartProduct, (Boolean)->Unit)->Unit)? = null
    var onProductClickListener: ((CartItem.CartProduct)->Unit)? = null
    var onWarnMaxCount: ((CartItem.CartProduct)->Unit)? = null

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CartItemViewHolder {
        val productView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.cart_item,parent,false)
        return CartItemViewHolder(productView)
    }

    private val differCallback = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<CartItem>(){
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: CartItem, newItem: CartItem): Boolean {
            return  oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        @SuppressLint("DiffUtilEquals")
        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: CartItem, newItem: CartItem): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }

    }

    val differ = AsyncListDiffer(this,differCallback)


    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CartItemViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val item: CartItem = differ.currentList[position]

        holder.apply {
            sellerTitle.text = item.market_name
            if (productsRecycler.adapter == null) {
                val adapter = CartProductRecyclerAdapter(context)
                adapter.shippingTime = item.shipping_time
                adapter.onRemoveClickListener = onRemoveListener
                adapter.onUpdateListener = onUpdateListener
                adapter.onProductClickListener = onProductClickListener
                adapter.onWarnMaxCount = onWarnMaxCount
                productsRecycler.adapter = adapter
            }
            (productsRecycler.adapter as? CartProductRecyclerAdapter)?.differ?.submitList(item.products)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return differ.currentList.size
    }

    class CartItemViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val sellerTitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.seller_title)
        val productsRecycler: RecyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_recycler)
    }

}
```

CaerProductRecyclerAdapter

```
class CartProductRecyclerAdapter(val context: Context) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<CartProductRecyclerAdapter.CartProductViewHolder>(){

    var shippingTime: Int? = null
    var onRemoveClickListener: ((Int)->Unit)? = null
    var onUpdateListener: ((CartItem.CartProduct, (Boolean)->Unit)->Unit)? = null
    var onProductClickListener: ((CartItem.CartProduct)->Unit)? = null
    var onWarnMaxCount: ((CartItem.CartProduct)->Unit)? = null

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CartProductViewHolder {
        val productView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.cart_product_item,parent,false)
        return CartProductViewHolder(productView)
    }

    private val differCallback = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<CartItem.CartProduct>(){
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: CartItem.CartProduct, newItem: CartItem.CartProduct): Boolean {
            return  oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        @SuppressLint("DiffUtilEquals")
        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: CartItem.CartProduct, newItem: CartItem.CartProduct): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }

    }

    val differ = AsyncListDiffer(this,differCallback)


    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CartProductViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val item = differ.currentList[position]

        holder.apply {
            title.text = HtmlCompat.fromHtml("<b>${item.brand ?: ""}</b> ${item.name}", HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)

            Picasso.get().load(item.image?.thumbnail).into(image)

            setQuantityPrice(item, holder)
            
            optionKey.isVisible = item.option != null
            optionValue.isVisible = item.option != null
            if (item.option != null){
                optionKey.text = item.option.option.name + ": "
                optionValue.text = item.option.value.name
            }

            divider.isVisible = (position != differ.currentList.size - 1)
        }
    }

    private fun setQuantityPrice(item: CartItem.CartProduct, holder: CartProductRecyclerAdapter.CartProductViewHolder) {
        holder.apply {
            price.text = PriceFormatter.getPrice(item.price * item.quantity.toDouble())
            oldPrice.paintFlags = oldPrice.paintFlags or Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
            oldPrice.text = if (item.oldPrice != null){
                PriceFormatter.getPrice(item.oldPrice!! * item.quantity.toDouble())
            } else {
                null
            }
            quantity.text = "${item.quantity}"

            Log.e("mlog", " ${image.height} ${dataCont.height + actionCont.height}")
            val h = image.height - dataCont.height - actionCont.height
            val top = if (h > 0) h else 0
            actionCont.setPadding(0, top, 0, 0 )
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return differ.currentList.size
    }

    inner class CartProductViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

        val title: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title)
        val image: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image)
        val optionKey: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.option_key)
        val optionValue: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.option_value)
        val oldPrice: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.old_price)
        val price: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.price)
        val quantity: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantity)
        val increase: ImageButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantity_increase)
        val decrease: ImageButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantity_decrease)
        val remove: ImageButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_remove)
        val divider: View = itemView.findViewById(R.id.divider)

        val dataCont: View = itemView.findViewById(R.id.data_container)
        val actionCont: View = itemView.findViewById(R.id.action_container)

        val shipping: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.shipping)
        val shippingCont: View = itemView.findViewById(R.id.shipping_cont)

        init {
            remove.setOnClickListener {
                val item = differ.currentList[layoutPosition]
                onRemoveClickListener?.invoke(item.v_id)
            }
            increase.setOnClickListener {
                val item = differ.currentList[layoutPosition]
                if (item.inc() == null){
                    onWarnMaxCount?.invoke(item)
                    return@setOnClickListener
                }
                setQuantityPrice(item, this)
                onUpdateListener?.invoke(item){
                    if (!it){
                        item.dec()
                        setQuantityPrice(item, this)
                    }
                }
            }
            decrease.setOnClickListener {
                val item = differ.currentList[layoutPosition]
                if (item.dec() == null){
                    onRemoveClickListener?.invoke(item.v_id)
                    return@setOnClickListener
                }
                setQuantityPrice(item, this)
                onUpdateListener?.invoke(item){
                    if (!it){
                        item.inc()
                        setQuantityPrice(item, this)

                    }
                }
            }
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                val item = differ.currentList[layoutPosition]
                onProductClickListener?.invoke(item)
            }

            shippingCont.isVisible = shippingTime != null
            shipping.text = String.format(context.getString(R.string._deliv_hours), shippingTime)

        }

    }

}
```